# How to add Transparent to ColorDialog in C#

Tags: c#, transparent, colordialog

I want to add Transparent Color to my ColorDialog.

I tried this code :

```
MyDialog.CustomColors = new int[] { Color.Transparent.ToArgb() };    
MyDialog.ShowDialog();    
string hex = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(MyDialog.Color);    
MessageBox.Show(hex);
```

But, when I pick my Custom Color (I mean Transparent), the messageBox show me "White" instead of "Transparent". convert to White itself. But I want to pick Transparent. How can I do that?

Comment: are you using winforms?

Comment: yeah Its winform @karthick

Comment: IMO you need to create custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is showing the colour behind. Please post your control XAML to be sure.

A common workaround to that is to put a chequerboard pattern behind your swatch control, so that as the alpha is decreased, the chequer shows through. Otherwise, how else do you show something that has no visibility?

Comment: its all my code, actually in my project I want to save Color to my DataBase and user should to can choose "Transparent". I dont know how to do that by ColorDialog....

Comment: yeah there arent any related code to that. I just want to add the selected color to dataBase

Comment: Not sure what you mean - did you create a custom control to act as your color dialog? If not, create one - you can represent transparent however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The CustomColors property accepts colors in an Int32 composed of the BGR (blue, green, red) and you are passing it an ARGB representation of Transparent color. The A in ARGB  controls the alpha channel and transparency. I would put a check box on the form for user to specify color transparency . Else you may map your white in the color dialog box to transparent selection.

```
If (dlgCol.Color.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb() )
 {
        btnColor.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

 }
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space